# Job for service failed because the control process exited with error

Tags: linux, bash, python, services, systemctl

**I'm trying to run a service manually, and everytime I get the folling messages:**

```
user1@machine:~/Tools/systemd_tools$ sudo systemctl status tool_fd.service
● tool_fd.service - automatic tool service
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/tool_fd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-06-20 14:30:00 CEST; 8min ago
  Process: 17796 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/Bureau/test_tool/Tool.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17796 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Request for data 72h"

juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:     '_open', req)
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:     result = func(*args)
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1235, in http_open
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:     return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1205, in do_open
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]:     raise URLError(err)
juin 20 14:30:00 machine python2.7[17796]: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
juin 20 14:30:00 machine systemd[1]: tool_fd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
juin 20 14:30:00 machine systemd[1]: tool_fd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

user1@machine:~/Tools/systemd_tools$ sudo systemctl start tool_fd.servic                                                                                                                                                            e
Job for tool_fd.service failed because the control process exited with error                                                                                                                                                           code.


user1@machine:~/Tools/systemd_tools$ systemctl --failed
  UNIT                LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● tool_fd.service loaded failed failed automatic tool service

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What user is your service running as?  Does this user have access to `Bureau`'s files?  Have you tried running the same command directly or does it require running as a specific user?  We have enough to ask you what needs to be known as long as you add the answer to these questions to your question.

Comment: You solution is probably going to require you to run the commands being run from the .service file directly to troubleshoot.  There are tricks for doing this but need the answers to my questions.

Comment: The user have access to all the files include the Bureau'files ( by user i mean a specific ID ) . Yes i tried to running it directly.

Comment: That error given does not tell us why it failed. It's been cut off. You need to post all of the output from the systemd logs. But if it runs from the command line, then it may be either permission problems, or you need to specify full paths.

Comment: Could you tell me please , what do you mean by a permission problem ? is it from the python version ? this service run a .python file , for the full path i'm running this service in /run/systemd/system , can you tell if this problem related to the static word in this line ==> "Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/tool_fd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)"